# How to choose key and query from dynamoDb for ordered objects

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Suppose I have an object like

```
{
    epochTime : 1527174282
    action : create
    state : fail
}
```

From the documentation of AWS, to query

> You must specify the partition key name and value as an equality
> condition.
>
> You can optionally provide a second condition for the sort key (if
> present).

In the case where I just want to query some item from A to B from the whole dataset ( Just want to use the sort key ) how should I chooe the hash key and query for this kind of data to work effectively?

Comment: Use a Scan with an ExpressionFilter.

Comment: Wouldn't a scan be slow without any kind of pre-sort / index ? @Stu

Comment: You said you wanted to query the whole dataset, which is exactly what a scan does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define secondary index for the attribute with the primary key (hash) as the field and perform scan on the secondary index

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html

Working with scans
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html

Also refer this java sdk examples for working with secondary index and scans https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSIJavaDocumentAPI.Example.html

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/02/10/secondary-index-scan-a-simpler-way-to-scan-dynamodb-table/

Comment: Would it be slow to use scan?
How would it fare compare to traditional mySql - style database?
For example, when I want to get first X item?

Comment: No as it is secondary indexed. I think the performance would just be the scan as we are operating on indices. Even if you would go for sql style database then too you will scan on indexed field i suppose. Please mark the answer right if it helps